# How do I slide - animate a UITableView in a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, catransition

I want to slide a UITableVIew into a view (NOT by pushing the view on top of Navigation Controller) on click of a button and then hide it back by sliding , on clicking of the same button.
I want the tableView to slide inside a present view.

Comment: Have you tried doing it at all? Try writing an animation block which moves the view onto the screen and moves it off, and then execute it. The very first thing you should look up when thinking about animating is how [view animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You animate the frame property of the table view to move it off screen or back onto screen.

Here is some sample code that moves a table view off screen and moves another on screen in its place:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kSlideTableDuration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(tableAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];

self.tableView1.frame = offScreen;
self.tableView2.frame = onScreen;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can read about animation blocks like this in the [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation of [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  To implement you would do something similar to this:

```
iPhoneCustomViewController *newView = [[iPhoneCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPhoneCustomViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
[newView release];
```

Then, when your done with the CustomViewController do:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the nice slide animations for free if you use a `UINavigationController`. It will take care of sliding views in (push them on the navigation controller stack) and sliding them out (pop them off the navigation controller stack).