# Three20 openURLAction and navigationController's popViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
- (IBAction) onBackButtonTouch: (id)sender{
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction: [[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://somePage"] applyAnimated:YES]];}
```

The result of this code "slides" the view controller from left to right. (I don't know what the exact term is).

Now I want to use

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I would like to customize the animation to slide the currently viewed controller from
left to right, right to left, top to bottom, bottom to top

How do we do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can configure how the nav controller pops a view off the stack.

But what I think you are looking for is UIView Animations.

Here's another Stack overflow post on that:
  [How do I slide - animate a UITableView in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342404/how-do-i-slide-animate-a-uitableview-in-a-view)